# Chrome shut down in Catalina OS with Error

Tags: macos, google-chrome, cpu

The Google Chrome shut down in the Catalina OS X with the following error message:

```
Process:               Google Chrome [990]
Path:                  /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome
Identifier:            com.google.Chrome
Version:               ???
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Google Chrome [990]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2020-09-10 11:12:22.133 +0600
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.15.6 (19G2021)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        71576168-94E4-4836-ACC6-B511700981F5


Time Awake Since Boot: 1100 seconds

System Integrity Protection: disabled

Crashed Thread:        0

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (Code Signature Invalid)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Reason:    Namespace CODESIGNING, Code 0x1

kernel messages:

VM Regions Near 0 (cr2):
--> 
    __TEXT                 00000001062a6000-00000001062cf000 [  164K] r-x/r-x SM=COW  

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   @<|                            0x000000010d95c000 _dyld_start + 0

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x0000000000000000  rcx: 0x0000000000000000  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x0000000000000000  rsi: 0x0000000000000000  rbp: 0x0000000000000000  rsp: 0x00007ffee9959be8
   r8: 0x0000000000000000   r9: 0x0000000000000000  r10: 0x0000000000000000  r11: 0x0000000000000000
  r12: 0x0000000000000000  r13: 0x0000000000000000  r14: 0x0000000000000000  r15: 0x0000000000000000
  rip: 0x000000010d95c000  rfl: 0x0000000000000200  cr2: 0x0000000000000000
  
Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x00000000
Trap Number:     0


Binary Images:
       0x1062a6000 -        0x1062ceff7 +@<| (0) <624A11B8-529E-3881-8BA5-0EF01431CE6D> @<|
       0x10d95b000 -        0x10d9ecf47 +@<| (750.6) <F9D4DEDC-8296-3E3F-B517-9C8B89A4C094> @<|

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 632
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=1000K resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=1000K(100%)
Writable regions: Total=8408K written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=8408K(100%)
 
                                VIRTUAL   REGION 
REGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) 
===========                     =======  ======= 
STACK GUARD                       56.0M        1 
Stack                             8192K        1 
__DATA                             232K        4 
__DATA_CONST                        20K        1 
__LINKEDIT                         252K        2 
__TEXT                             748K        2 
shared memory                        8K        2 
===========                     =======  ======= 
TOTAL                             65.2M       13 

Model: MacBookPro8,2, BootROM 87.0.0.0.0, 4 processors, Quad-Core Intel Core i7, 2.2 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 1.69f4
Graphics: kHW_IntelHD3000Item, Intel HD Graphics 3000, spdisplays_builtin
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D5434314753364D465238432D50422020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x855D, -
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xD6), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.102.31)
Bluetooth: Version 7.0.6f7, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: Samsung SSD 860 QVO 1TB, 1 TB
Serial ATA Device: OPTIARC DVD RW AD-5970H
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: IR Receiver
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: BRCM2070 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 22.1
```

Does anyone know what to do about it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to change the codesign of the application.

Run the following commands:

```
xattr -lr /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app
xattr -cr /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app
sudo codesign -f -s - /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app
```

If you have installed Google Chrome in another place, use it instead of `/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app`

Comment: this should be marked as the correct answer, many thanks @Ever Dev

Comment: Agree, this should be the accepted answer. Works for other apps too like Word, Outlook etc. Although the xattr -lr command is unnecessary.

Comment: @Ever,  I accepted this as the correct answer. I have the same issue again after I re-installed the OS, and your answer saved me :)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the app isn't correctly signed. Also you seem to have switched off SIP, which can cause things to fail. Don't leave SIP off, just toggle it if you need to do specific work without it, then switch it straight back on.

Additionally, you are running an OS which is not supported on that computer - presumably using dosDude's installer hack. MacBookPro8,2 is only supported up to High Sierra.
The reason it's not supported is because your GPU is not Metal-capable.

Basically… a bridge too far. Expect random issues; or roll back to High Sierra.

Comment: I run Chrome from the terminal and it started fine. Yes, I installed the Catalina OS using the dosDude's installer hack on MacBookPro8,2.  You won't believe everything is perfect till not, the only issue that I am having occasionally is with the Google products.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

```
cd '/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS'
./Google\ Chrome &
```

If you cant run the Chrome after this step, kill the process and try again:

```
./Google\ Chrome &
[1] 53333

# Chrome didnt run and try again
kill -9  53333
./Google\ Chrome &
```

When it run, allow the notifications and then, it will run properly from the terminal as usual.